# Add lines to JPanel during execution

Tags: java, swing, jpanel

I'm trying to figure out what would be the most optimal way of drawing lines in a `JPanel`. The panel is called at the beginning of the execution but the X and Y positions are be passed on after selecting an XML file and parsing said file.

So far I've using `JPanel mypanel.add(new JLabel())` for images but I'm not sure how to add lines.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please make your question a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example [M.C.V E](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Also check [how to ask question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to make your post answerable.

Comment: See [Custom Painting](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html) and [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46577656/3992939)

Comment: @Prateek good suggestion, and a tip: `[mcve]` auto expands to [mcve].

Comment: *"So far I've using `JPanel mypanel.add(new JLabel())` for images but I'm not sure how to add lines."* Lines can be drawn to an image. Here is [an example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12683632/418556).